# Multiple primary keys found issue Laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, migration, laravel-5, primary-key

here is the issue. I am banging my head for hours now on this. Laravel is not allowing me to have a primary key (it says multiple but you can see it has only one). And further more as there is issue causing in primary key in teachers table. I am not able to use this as a foreign key in courses table.

**Migration file for teacher table**

```
class CreateTeachersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('teachers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('teacher_id')->primary();
            $table->string('email', 200);
            $table->string('first_name',300)->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name',300)->nullable();
            $table->string('account_status',50)->default('inactive');
            $table->string('subscription_status',50);
            $table->string('account_reset_code',400)->nullable();
            $table->string('passkey',500);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('teachers');
    }
}
```

**Migration File for courses table**

```
class CreateCoursesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
         Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('course_id')->primary();
            $table->integer('teacher_id_fr');
            $table->string('course_name', 500);
            $table->string('course_code',300);
            $table->string('subject_area',300);
            $table->string('course_level',100);;
            $table->string('grade_periods',100);
            $table->timestamps();    
        });

        Schema::table('courses',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('teacher_id_fr')->references('teacher_id')->on('teachers')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('courses');
    }
}
```

**Issue raised on migrating**

> Syntax Error or access violation. 1068 Multiple primary keys found

.

**What I've tried by now**

**1)** Making the primary column unsigned using unsigned method.

**2)** using InnnoDB engine type for table.

**3)** And much other things as suggested for similiar posts on the forums but nothing seems to work for me.

**EDIT**

I've removed the primary() method from both files at $table->increments('teacher_id'). As this is said Laravel marks auto increments columns as primary keys.

But now the **error** is on courses table as it says.

> General error : 1215 cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: which migration file is generating the error ?

Comment: Thanks @jaysingkar for your time, teachers file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with a minute change. I modified courses migration file like below and it worked like a charm

```
$table -> integer('teacher_id_fr') -> unsigned();
```

**Reason**

Actually both the referenced and referencing columns (teacher.teacher_id and course.teacher_id_fr in this case) must be of same type.

Having said that, Laravel marks autoincrement columns as "Primary" and of type unsigned. So make sure to change foregin key column to match the type of primary key i.e unsigned. which the above modification does.

Hope it clarifies the issue and solution. If you have anything else on your mind. Please give it a shot here.

Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

You can define Multiple primanry key in migration file as below:

```
$table->primary(array('field_name1', 'field_name2'));
```

Comment: Bhavin, Thanks for your time. I've read that also. But I don't want them as you can see I am only using a single column.

I've edited the post to new changes please check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this, remove `primary()`, `increments` automatically creates it `primary`

```
 $table->increments('teacher_id')->primary();
```

to

```
$table->increments('teacher_id');
```

For new error try this `General error : 1215 cannot add foreign key constraint`

```
public function up()
{
     Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('course_id');
        $table->integer('teacher_id_fr');
        $table->string('course_name', 500);
        $table->string('course_code',300);
        $table->string('subject_area',300);
        $table->string('course_level',100);;
        $table->string('grade_periods',100);
        $table->timestamps();    

        $table->foreign('teacher_id_fr')
        ->references('teacher_id')->on('teachers')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');

    });
}
```

Comment: Rishi, Just tried that . see the edit. It generates another error now on courses table at foreign key.

Comment: This is from starting or you are getting only this time this issue ?

Comment: From the start. I kept trying multiple solutions as suggested on forums.

Comment: Can you try also this : `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';`

Comment: Already tried that Rishi, as mentioned in the post It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Rishi, I am using Phpmyadmin, When I run php artisan migrate, although it generates the error but it creates the courses table.

Comment: did you also try by replacing `teacher_id` and `course_id` to just `id` and change in code where you make `foreign` key

Comment: Rishi, Yes I also tried that. But Fortunately I am able to fix the issue. 
Actually when we reference a column in our child table it must have the same type as in the parent table. Laravel marks the autoincrement columns as "primary" and "UNSIGNED". I just changed it as 

$table->integer('teacher_id_fr')->unsigned(); which makes it of same type as primary key. So it works like a charm

Thanks for your time again

Comment: Thanks for this info too :)